# Transform ranged data in an Access table

Tags: database, ms-access, transform

I have a table in Access database as below;

```
Name | Range   | X  | Y  | Z
------------------------------
A    | 100-200 | 1  | 2  | 3
A    | 200-300 | 4  | 5  | 6
B    | 100-200 | 10 | 11 | 12
B    | 200-300 | 13 | 14 | 15
C    | 200-300 | 16 | 17 | 18
C    | 300-400 | 19 | 20 | 21
```

I have trying write a query that convert this into the following format.

```
Name | X_100_200 | Y_100_200 | Z_100_200 | X_200_300 | Y_200_300 | Z_200_300 | X_300_400 | Y_300_400 | Z_300_400 
A    | 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         | 6         |           |           | 
B    | 10        | 11        | 12        | 13        | 14        | 15        |           |           |
C    |           |           |           | 16        | 17        | 18        | 19        | 20        | 21
```

After trying for a while the best method I could come-up with is to write bunch of short queries that selects the data for each Range and then put them together again using a Union query. The problem is that for this example I have shown 3 columns (X, Y and Z), but I actually have much more.  Access is starting to strain with the amount of SQL I have come up with.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.  Just use Access Pivotview.  Finding it hard to export the results to Excel though.